# How to open a file with a specific extension using Applescript

Tags: applescript-objc

I would like to know how do I open a file with a specific extension
Inside the downloads folder. I try this:

```
set downloads to "~/Downloads"
            set fileExtension to ("pkg")
            open every file of downloads whose name extension is fileExtension
```

I know I could use:

```
do shell script "open ~/Downloads/blabla.pkg"
```

and this would work fine but with every update the file changes its name and this would not be interesting to me.
thanks advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `do shell script` can use a string for a path,  AppleScript itself has limited file handling abilities, so you need to tell it to use something that does, such as the **Finder** or **System Events**.  A [file specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28) (such as `alias`, `file`, or application scripting terms such as `folder` or `disk item`) also needs to be used to differentiate a file item from a regular string (such as a POSIX path).  Depending on the application used, there may be other differences from the shell, such as tilde expansion, so the **StandardAdditions** scripting addition provides paths to common locations:

```
set fileExtension to ("pkg")
tell application "System Events"
  repeat with anItem in (get every file of (path to downloads folder) whose name extension is fileExtension)
    open anItem
  end repeat
end tell
```

Also note that using the filter reference form “whose” only works with application objects, and not regular lists or records.  AppleScriptObjC also has access to Cocoa methods, so you can use the **NSWorkSpace** or **NSFileManager** classes, although going that route tends to get a bit more verbose.

Comment: thanks for your replay, but not work Error: Can’t get every file of "~/Downloads/myFolder" I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Depending on what you are using, the Finder doesn't know about posix paths, and System Events doesn't expand the tilde (that is why I used the built-in `path to downloads folder`)

Comment: Is there a way around this?

Comment: @red_menace _System Events_ **does** expand the tilde (**System info:** _AppleScript version:_ 2.7  _System version:_ 10.13.6).  He needs to add a `folder` object specifier before `"~/Downloads/myFolder"`, i.e. `get every file of folder "~/Downloads/myFolder" whose...` (within the _System Events_ `tell` block, of course).

Comment: @CJK this: ```
set fileExtension to ("pkg")
            tell application "System Events"
                repeat with anItem in (get every file of "~/Downloads/myFolder" whose name extension is fileExtension)
                    open anItem
                end repeat
            end tell
```

Comment: @TheOnlyOneHere No, read my last comment again carefully, after the "i.e.".  You need the specifier `folder` before your folder path.

Comment: @red_menace 99% of your answer is right I will mark it as right, but please edit as soon as possible and thanks for your help!